# Define Return value as * or & based on custom Iterator<T>

Tags: c++, templates, reference, iterator, return-type

**Updated**

I am working on some container code in an environment where I the STL is not available to me. I am trying to generalize my iterators to reduce code duplication. I've encountered a case where I have a container that can contain Objects or pointers to Objects. I am having a compilation problem when trying to compile the following (contrived) code:

```
struct Object
{
};

template<typename Container, typename T>
struct IteratorBase
{
    IteratorBase( Container * container, T curr ) : _container( container ), _curr( curr ) { }

    Container * _container;
    T           _curr;

    T &         GetValue() const { return _curr; }

    void        Invalidate() { _curr = NULL; }
};


template<typename T>
struct Container
{
    typedef typename T * Type;

    typedef IteratorBase<Container<T>, Type>            Iterator;

    Iterator        GetIterator() { return Iterator( this, storage ); }

    T               storage[10];
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Container<Object> containerByAddress;

    const Object* pA = containerByAddress.GetIterator().GetValue();

    return 0;
}
```

The error is

```
error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'Object *const ' to 'Object *&'
while compiling class template member function 'Object &IteratorBase<Container,T>::GetValue(void) const'
```

So I have made some changes to change how the value is returned by deducing the type of T using the following:

```
template<typename T>
struct DetermineReturnType
{
    typedef T &     ReturnType;
};

template<typename T>
struct DetermineReturnType<T*>
{
    typedef  T *    ReturnType;
};

template<typename Container, typename T>
struct IteratorBase
{
    IteratorBase( Container * container, T curr ) : _container( container ), _curr( curr ) { }

    Container * _container;
    T           _curr;

    typedef typename DetermineReturnType<T>::ReturnType ReturnType;

    ReturnType  GetValue() const { return _curr; }

    void        Invalidate() { _curr = NULL; }
};
```

Now my iterator uses & or * based on T.

But my question is - is this a reasonable solution? is there something I can do to fix this?

Please note I cannot use STL, Boost, nor latest version of C++ as this is an embedded system some years old.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: `Object * & GetValue();` should be ok if you have pointers stored in the same way as values. Why do you say they are temporaries and cannot be returned this way?

Comment: I see no reason to use specialization here. If `T` is `Object*` then `T& GetValue()` will already be `Object*& GetValue()`.

Comment: Yes, you are both right. When I extend my sample, everything is working right, yet in the dense thicket of the actual code this isn't compiling, and it seems to be related to  *'s, &'s an const. Likely I have the const in the wrong spot. I'll do more digging and write back.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious - So there is no problem with Object * a = iterator.GetValue() where T is Object* even though the function signature is Object * & Iterator::GetValue() ?

Comment: Correct. You're just returning a reference to an element in your container and copying the referenced value into `a`. The fact that it's a pointer value is irrelevant, it's still a value. FWIW the pointer should not be an rvalue (temporary) if you've implemented `GetValue()` correctly.

Comment: @Steven [No problem.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c0bff5c7b82b3f9)

Comment: @Captain Obvlious - I think that's the problem - I've updated the sample to include the code that breaks as well as why I used the fix. The error is "'return' : cannot convert from 'Object *const ' to 'Object *&'" which sounds a lot like a rvalue problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `GetValue()` is declared `const` but you are returning a non-`const` reference to a member variable. If the compiler allowed you do to this you would be able to modify the member variable in a possibly `const` qualified instance of the iterator. You can solve this pretty easily by providing both a `const` and non-`const` version of `GetValue()`. The compiler will choose the appropriate version based on the CV qualifiers of the iterator instance.

```
T const& GetValue() const { return _curr; }
T& GetValue() { return _curr; }
```

Unfortunately this is not likely going to get you the real behavior you are looking for. You really should not be returning a reference here as it will only allow you to change the element inside iterator rather than the element in the container. To get where you want you'll need to change more than just the `GetValue` implementation and redesign your iterators to work with the elements in the container rather than maintaining it locally.

Below is a basic example of how you might approach this. It returns a reference to the element in the container allowing you to modify the container through the iterator. Since I don't have a full version of your `Container` I'm using naked arrays but the visible end result should be easy to grasp.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Object { };

template<typename T>
struct IteratorBase
{
    IteratorBase(T* initialPtr) : _curr(initialPtr) {}
    T* _curr;

    T const & GetValue() const { return *_curr; }
    T& GetValue() { return *_curr; }
    void next() { ++_curr; }
    void prev() { --_curr; }
};

int main()
{
    Object a, b, c, d, e;
    Object  *objects[] = { &a, &b, &c, &d, &e };
    IteratorBase<Object*> it(objects);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(objects) / sizeof(*objects); i++)
    {
        std::cout << it.GetValue() << "\n";
        it.GetValue() = NULL;
        it.next();
    }

    it = IteratorBase<Object*>(objects);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(objects) / sizeof(*objects); i++)
    {
        std::cout << it.GetValue() << "\n";
        it.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Caption Obvlious - that does indeed appear to solve the problem and I can understand why. It's simply the thicket of iterators, typedefs, and iterator interfaces to the containers plus old unit test framework that is making this a struggle. I appreciate the help. Once I finish up my changes to the twenty odd containers I'll mark it answered.

Comment: I guess the reason why my previous solution with a & or * selector worked is that it returned a copy of the pointer, instead of a reference to it. Which do you think is desirable or preferred?

Comment: After taking a closer look at your implementation you should not be returning a reference but plain old pointer instead. If you want to return a reference you should return one that references the element in the container rather than a member of the iterator. The reason for this is because by returning the reference you can change what the iterator is pointing to, if you reference the element in the container you change the contents of the container instead.

Comment: Well, given a Container<Object*>, and an iterator, invoking the Container<Object*>::Iterator::GetValue() should give me an Object* I can manipulate. So yes, I should be returning a pointer. However, in some cases the Container type is a Container<Object> - not a pointer, but stored by value. Consider a Vector<Object>, or Set<Object> - and now I want my iterator's GetValue to return a reference to that Object, both to avoid copy-by-value, and also to allow the object to be changed. Hence DeduceReturnType<T> - so that GetValue() would return by reference for value types, and pointer by pointer.

Comment: To be clear I am using the word 'Container' in a generic sense. I have Lists, Maps, Sets, HashTables, and I am trying to reuse the basic iterator interface to minimize code duplication.

Comment: Why does this work with IteratorBase<Object*> it(objects), but not IteratorBase<const Object*> it(objects)? I get "Invalid conversion from 'Object**' to 'const Object**'. I'm trying to get const iterator semantics so that the iterator returns unmodifiable elements through GetValue()

Comment: @Steven Because `const T** and `T**` are different types. If you want `const_iterator` semantics you need to provide an additional iterator type like `ConstIteratorBase`.